# How to query a particular job id submitted in bigquery action

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-python-api

I have been using `google_cloud` for submitting a job to `big query` for extraction of the file to `GCS` like this:

```
dataset = self.bqClient.dataset(self.website_id)
table = dataset.table(table_name)
job_name = str(uuid.uuid4())
job = self.bqClient.extract_table_to_storage(
job_name, table, destination)
job.destination_format = "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON"
job.compression = 'GZIP'
job.begin()
```

Here the job `id` or `name` is the `uuid4`. Basically I am collecting these job `ids` in a `queue` and want to check later if that `job` is in `DONE` state. How can I do that?

I have been searching for this but so far had no luck. I was only able to find the function - `client.list_jobs()` but it's the list of all `jobs`. I only want to `query` or `search` for one particular `job`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just filter out by the `name` attribute which job you want.

Let's say you want to get information about a job whose `id` is "big name string job 1". You can filter it out from the list of jobs by running:

```
job_name = "big name string job 1"
job = [job for job in list(self.bqClient.list_jobs()) if job.name == job_name][0] # this will break if list is empty

print(job.state) # DONE or RUNNING
```

Just make sure to update the client if possible, currently we are ate version `0.26.0`

[EDIT]:

You said in your comment about having 1 million jobs. As far as running the [get job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get) method, currently the API does so only when running the [exists](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py#L376) and the [reload](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py#L400) methods so there's no way of running something like `client.get_job(job_name)`.

Still, in the `list_job`, you can send the arguments `all_users` and `state_filter` as in the [code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py#L225), something like:

```
job_name = "big name string job 1"
job = [job for job in list(self.bqClient.list_jobs(all_users=False, state_filter='done')) if job.name == job_name][0]
```

Which lists jobs only for current user authorized in the client with given state.

If still this lists millions, then you could still (somewhat "hacky" solution) query it directly from the job base constructor, something like:

```
from google.cloud.bigquery.job import _AsyncJob
job = _AsyncJob(job_name, self.bqClient)
job.reload()
print(job.state) #RUNNING or DONE
```

Which is an indirect way of running a `client.get_job()`.

This might be an interesting feature request for the python repository.

Comment: Let's if there are 1 million jobs then also this option?

Comment: @NikhilParmar I edited my answer with new information

Comment: awesome amazing thanks! let me try thesr and let you know